# Input file variable with Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i need to solve one little problem.
i tried to send with jquery the tmp image but the result is undefined.
My Code:

```
    $(document).on("click",".subImagen", function(e) {

    // VARIABLES
    //var imagen = $('#sbImagen').val();
    var imagen = $('#sbImagen')[0].files[0];
    var imagenSize = $('#sbImagen')[0].files[0].size;
    var imagenNombre = $('#sbImagen')[0].files[0].name;
    var imagenType = $('#sbImagen')[0].files[0].type;
    var params = '&imagen='+imagen+'&imagenSize='+imagenSize+'&imagenNombre='+imagenNombre+'&imagenType='+imagenType;       

    // ENVIO DE VARIABLES
    $.post('classes/subirImagen', params, function(jsondatareg){            
        if(jsondatareg.validacion == 'exito'){  
            var url = 'inventario_f';
            swal({
                title: "IMAGEN SUBIDA",
                text: jsondatareg.mensaje,
                timer: 2500,
                type: "success",
                showConfirmButton: false
            });
            setTimeout(function () {
                window.location = url;
            }, 3000);
        }
        if(jsondatareg.validacion == 'error'){              
            swal({
                title: "ERROR",
                text: jsondatareg.mensaje,
                timer: 2500,
                type: "error",
                showConfirmButton: false
            });
        }
    },'json');  
});
```

This code works fine but i need to send **tmp_name** too.

The php code:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8");

$imagen = $_REQUEST['imagen'];
$imagenSize = $_REQUEST['imagenSize'];
$imagenNombre = $_REQUEST['imagenNombre'];
$imagenType = $_REQUEST['imagenType'];

if (($imagenNombre == !NULL) && ($imagenSize <= 20000000)){
    if ($imagenType == "image/png"){
        $directorio = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/assets/images/productos/';
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'],$directorio.$imagenNombre); 
        $datareg['validacion']  = 'exito';
        $datareg['mensaje'] = "SE HA SUBIDO LA IMAGEN CORRECTAMENTE.";
    }else{
        $datareg['validacion']  = 'error';
        $datareg['mensaje'] = "LA IMAGEN QUE INTENTAS SUBIR NO TIENE EL FORMATO .PNG";
    }
}else{
    if($imagenNombre == !NULL){ 
        $datareg['validacion']  = 'error';
        $datareg['mensaje'] = "LA IMAGEN SUPERA EL TAMAÑO PERMITIDO.";
    }else{ 
        $datareg['validacion']  = 'error';
        $datareg['mensaje'] = "NO HAS PUESTO NINGUNA IMAGEN.";
    }   
}
echo json_encode($datareg);
?>
```

The problem is the next line: **move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'],$directorio.$imagenNombre);** because i can't send the **$_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name']** with jquery. How can i fix that?

[Variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2Ktm.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience I don't think it will be possible to get tmp_name as this refers to the temporary location of the file stored on the server when a file gets uploaded. What you probably want to do is upload the file using ajax. It should achieve a similar affect to what you're already doing :)

With ajax you can send your image object using FileData as shown in the html below:

```
<form class="form" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="upload-file">
</form>
```

and then in jQuery, on a upload button click event:

```
var formData = new FormData($('.form')[0]);

                $.ajax({
                    url: "upload.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: formData,
                    contentType: false,
                    cache: false,
                    processData:false,
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                       console.log('success');
                    }
                });
```

and then in your PHP file (in my example, called 'upload.php') you can user the $_FILE object to get your file and then derive any information from it that way...

```
$_FILES["csv-upload-file"]
```

Comment: If I do not use the form to make the shipment, can I send only the input by ajax?

Comment: @NeftaliAcosta It depends on what the input is...if the input is a file then I don't think so but if it's text, date, radio, checkbox, anything like that then you can. To do that you need to create your `FormData` object like in my example but slightly different so do `var formData = new FormData();` and then use `formData.append('variable_name', variable_value);` and then send that formData in the ajax, again like in my example.